# Number of total orders on set with $n$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Show that there exist $n!$ total orders on a set with $n$ elements.

Could someone help me with this problem?

I get why this is when seeing an example, just not sure how to write a formal proof.

---

Example:

For set $\{a,b,c\}$ with $3$ elements we get  $3! = 6$ total orders:

$\{a<b<c, a<c<b, b<a<c, b<c<a, c<a<b, c<b<a\}$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I saw that too. That helped me understand the question better, but I still wasn't sure how I would go about proving it. Does this still count as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest element can be any of $n$. Once this has been selected, the next smallest can be any of $n-1$.

Continuing in this way we obtain

$n$ x $(n-1)$ x ... x $1$ possibilities

i.e. $n!$.

Comment: Shouldn't you start with the biggest element? Since if you take the smallest there is no next smallest element?

Comment: The next smallest is the smallest remaining choice once you have selected the smallest.

Comment: Oh ok. Would it be wrong to start with the biggest element and then going n-1 until you're at 1?

Comment: No that would be fine. However since you wrote a<b<c it seems natural to start from the left.

Comment: Oooh that makes sense! Alright I totally get it now. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Any permutation of $n$ elements defines an order.